# Would blue light be effective to help average people when sunsets come much earlier in the day?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, brain, light

I know people with SAD (Seasonal Affective Disorder) benefit from blue light in the winter as night-time comes much earlier (in the UK, sunset is around 4pm in December, compared to 9pm in June).

However, during winter (say the UK), would the average person also benefit from more blue light in the late afternoon/early-evening than standard light bulbs currently supply?